# Remove Border On Focus From Button Control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am setting my Winforms Button control properties to appear as a hyperlink would on a web page. I've formatted everything fine, except the border in the FlatAppearance object. I have code to act as pseudo-CSS (FormBackColor is a string constant.):

```
b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
b.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(FormBackColor) 
b.ForeColor = Color.Blue
b.Font = New Font(b.Font.FontFamily, b.Font.Size, FontStyle.Underline)
b.Cursor = Cursors.Hand

Dim fa As FlatButtonAppearance = b.FlatAppearance
fa.BorderSize = 0
fa.MouseOverBackColor = b.BackColor
fa.MouseDownBackColor = b.BackColor

AddHandler b.MouseEnter, AddressOf ButtonMouseOver
AddHandler b.MouseLeave, AddressOf ButtonMouseOut
```

Here are the mouse out/over functions as a reference to what is going on:

```
Public Shared Sub ButtonMouseOver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Dim fa As FlatButtonAppearance = b.FlatAppearance
    fa.BorderSize = 1

End Sub

Public Shared Sub ButtonMouseOut(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Dim fa As FlatButtonAppearance = b.FlatAppearance
    fa.BorderSize = 0

End Sub
```

The code removes the border from the flat Button control except on MouseOver, where I add a 1 pixel border. On MouseLeave, I remove the border. This is to show some visual feedback. This works fine when the button does not have the focus. However, if I click on the button, giving the button focus, mousing out and over again now shows a greater than 1 pixel border around the button. I'm imagining it's combining my button's explicit 1 pixel border with the traditional "Winform Button has the focus, so add a border" border around the Button.

How can I disable/remove the "Winform Button has the focus, so add a border" border? Or, should I just do a check in ButtonMouseOver to check if the control has the focus, being a condition of adding the border, and just be done with it? I'd prefer to remove the automatic border from focus for whatever reason :)

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but is there a reason that you're trying to hack a button into doing the same thing that a LinkLabel was built for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the button's OnPaint event and re-paint over the drawn border with the form's background color:

```
AddHandler Button1.Paint, AddressOf ButtonPaint

Private Sub ButtonPaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Dim Btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Using P As New Pen(Me.BackColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(P, 1, 1, Btn.Width - 3, Btn.Height - 3)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this to to inherit the Windows.Forms.Button class and override the events. That prevents having to handle those events for every button in your main program.

```
Public Class BorderlessFlatButton
    Inherits Windows.Forms.Button

Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()
    MyBase.OnCreateControl()
    Me.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Me.BackColor
    Me.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Me.BackColor
    Me.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
    Me.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
    Me.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal pevent As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(pevent)
    Using P As New Pen(Me.BackColor)
        pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(P, 1, 1, Me.Width - 3, Me.Height - 3)
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

note: I'm not 100% sure "`OnCreateControl`" was the best event to use, but it worked in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

Derving from Button and setting the control style so that the control is not selectable:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Me.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        Me.FlatStyle = Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
        Me.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = SystemColors.ControlDarkDark
        Me.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Cyan
        Me.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = SystemColors.ControlDark

        Me.TabStop = False
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, False)
    End Sub
End Class
```